# Java Self Scheduling Program / Service?

Tags: java, scheduling

I am working on a simulation program in java, and we are finding that we need a lightweight java process to kick itself off at a certain (randomly generated) time, perform a few tasks, and then schedule the next task (randomly generated as well as generated from the results of the first task).

The program currently runs in a linux environment, but I would like to keep options open such that it could be run on OSX and Windows environments in the future.

How would I schedule these in java without using too much resources on the scheduling?

Comment: You can't have a process start off randomly unless it's made to be spawned randomly from another process. One Java process that at random intervals executes another Java process.

Comment: I guess I should clarify. That point. The first task is manually started, all tasks after that are randomly generated and based off of the results of the previous task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As recommended in [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) use it in favor of `Timer`

> A ThreadPoolExecutor that can additionally schedule commands to run
>   after a given delay, or to execute periodically. This class is
>   preferable to Timer when multiple worker threads are needed, or when
>   the additional flexibility or capabilities of ThreadPoolExecutor
>   (which this class extends) are required.

```
public class TaskTimer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService svc = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
        svc.schedule(new Task(svc), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

class Task implements Callable<Result> {

    private ScheduledExecutorService svc;

    public Task(ScheduledExecutorService svc) {
        this.svc = svc;
    }

    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        Result result = compute();
        Task t = nextTask(result);
        svc.schedule(t, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return result;
    }

    private Task nextTask(Result result) {
        return new Task(svc);
    }

    private Result compute() {
        System.out.println("Computing Result");
        return new Result();
    }

}

class Result {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For maximum portability let the java program run continuously and just do things at certain times using the standard java [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

If you want persistent timers, that are resistant to crashes and restarts, and if you don't mind using a Java EE server such as Glassfish (I would recommend it even for a lightweight task), then you can use the [persistent timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-basicexamples004.htm) that are standard in Java EE.

Comment: I think its fair to say that if such a continous program was written right it would use next to no resources.  (And if it isnt written right it can still go on the dailyWTF

Comment: Correct. Next to zero resources. It is extremely efficient. Additionally, the `Timer` has an interface to allow cancelling a previously scheduled task, also efficiently.

Comment: as a subsequent answer mentions, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is a better choice if your tasks are doing something non-trivial. `Timer` will cause "bunching" if your tasks take some time to complete that is significant relative to the resolution of the schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a priority queue

> essentially you put first task in to the priority queue
>
> pop it
>
> that in turns generates random tasks  assign priority to each of those
>   tasks
>
> the ordering will happen naturally when you add them to the priority
>   queue.
>
> start popping based on how much time you need to wait if a particular
>   tasks requires a particular time to wait.

[then do something like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411950/best-way-to-wait-in-java)